# What changes are needed to run a 32 bit software on a 64 bit system?

Tags: porting, legacy-code

If I have software written in C for 32 bit system, what changes do I need to make in it to run it on a 64 bit system?

Comment: Depends on platform.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  Be sure to take the Tour so you can see how things work here:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 3):

If the software is well-written, it should be none.  If the software makes assumptions as to the native word and pointer sizes, you'd have to track down and fix those.

Answer (score 1):

Most systems (like Windows and many Linux flavors) provide a sub system for that and will run your 32 bit executable with next to no overhead.

Ideally you could recompile it as a 64 bit program. Whether this works depends heavily on your actual code. Pointer Marg with assumed lengths will probably fail, bit well written code should run out of the box.